# Mvvmcross and better .net framework support PCL

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

What will be the best profile sweated for a PCL project targeting monodroid and monotouch only? Currently I can only use the profile 104, but that turns in pretty restrictive framework (very thin assemblies while both monodroid/monotouch cover much larger ".net" framework functionality.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe any significantly larger profile currently exists.

There is talk (and hope) of a new 'almost full' profile encompassing MonoTouch, MonoDroid and .Net4.5 in the future.

But today, the PCL profiles are defined as small subsets of full .Net - and you have to use extension mechanisms like plugins, PCLContrib, etc if you want larger capabilities.

With that said, I've seen a lot of sophisticated and rich apps built using Profile 104.

---

If the current PCL profiles are not sufficient for you, then you can of course, write your code in non-PCL code - at the price of having to maintain separate projects per platform. Redth tackled his WshLst project using this approach: https://github.com/Redth/WshLst/